# Is ADS-B receiver used in PixhawkCube ADS-B out or ADS-B In?

Tags: quadcopter

The new carrier boards for Pixhawk Cube seems to be using a 1090MHz **ADS-B receiver** from uAvionix. This receives location information from nearby aircraft (airplanes, gliders, helicopters, etc.), but will it also broadcast information to nearby vehicles as well or is it just a receiver?

I'm asking since there seems to be an ADS-B which sends and receives such information and is mandatory for aircrafts/quadcopters/helicopters/etc at specific airspace classes and not else where. It also seems there exists ADS-B out and ADS-B In, which I have no idea about their differences.

which of these two sensor is this one? is it only a receiver, or is it a full fledged ADS-B sensor?

Comment: read the manufacturer's datasheet for the device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a ADSB-In receiver. One can add a uAvionix ping200X, ping200XR, ping200SR, or ping20Si and all are transponders that respond to interrogation and also transmit ADSB Out.  https://uavionix.com/uas/